# Can I import an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary, hashmap

What I want to do is make a dictionary of all the tickers on AMEX, NYSE and NASDAQ markets and their associated names/shortened names. I have all the information I need in Excel, I just don't know how to transfer it into C#.

I am going to be using the dictionary to test user input.

Right now I am using an SQL database and the only input that works for searching for a company like Apple, is either its associated stock ticker `AAPL` or typing the full name of the company like `Apple Inc.`.

This is my dictionary setup, I have it in its own .cs file:

```
public class FinancialTickers
    {
        public string AssociatedName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

    }
```

Comment: try the nuget package `ExcelDataReader` https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Comment: Your question unclear, too broad and based on opinion. I know how to read `excel` sheets effectively - use `microsoft.ace.oledb` provider. Go from there. This is my opinion